# How do I setup ajax validation for happy.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, happy.js

In the [docs for happy.js](http://happyjs.com/) it says:

> 1. `arg` (anything): an optional second argument that will get passed to the test function. This is useful for comparing with another paramter or whatnot. If this is a function it will be evaluated. This way you can compare it to something that is evaluated at runtime such as what they put in another field or **to make a server call to check if a username is available, etc**.

What I want to know is how would I make a comparison using the `arg` parameter to check if an email already exists on the server?

Answer (score 0):

This would require a javascript function which makes an ajax call to some server-side code. The server-side code would do the email lookup and return a 'true' or 'false' value to the page depending on whether the email address exists.

So if you wrote such a function and called it 'doEmailLookup()' you would define the setup for field validation as:

```
$('#awesomeForm').isHappy({
fields: {
  '#email': {
    required: true,
    message: 'Your email was found on the server',
    test: doEmailLookup
  }
}
});
```

...where your doEmailLookup() function returned a 'false' value when the email address is found on the server.

Comment: Yes, but will happy.js stall until the ajax call returns the value from the server?

Comment: The function `doEmailLockup` can't synchronously return a true/false statement since the server request could take a few seconds to return an answer. There would have to be some kind of promise implementation for this to work using `happy.js`